# Why destructor runs before object is being deleted

Tags: c++, destructor

When I run this code destructor starts before object removal.

Code is here:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Testi {
public:

    string name;
    Testi(string a) : name(a) {
        cout << "Im alive: " << name << endl;
    }
    ~Testi() {
        cout << "Im no longer alive: " << name << endl;
    }

};
int main() {

    vector <Testi> a;

    a.push_back(Testi("John"));
    a.push_back(Testi("Jack"));
    a.push_back(Testi("Jake"));

    cout << a[1].name;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When i run program output is:

> Im alive: John
>   Im no longer alive: John
>   Im alive: Jack
>   Im no longer alive: John
>   Im no longer alive: Jack
>   Im alive: Jake
>   Im no longer alive: John
>   Im no longer alive: Jack
>   Im no longer alive: Jake
>
> Jack

And after input:

> Im no longer alive: John
>   Im no longer alive: Jack
>   Im no longer alive: Jake

So after every push_back() all destructors runs. The output operation works good so objects still exist.
For the 1st one destructor runs 4 times! Why?

Comment: Ok, but isn't it possible to copy whole code at once insted of line by line?

Comment: Yes. Paste the code in, select the entire block, and press Ctrl+K (or click the `{}` button in the toolbar). That magically indents each line by 4 spaces. You could also do this in a text editor of your choice and then paste it directly.

Comment: Right, thanks, now I will remember it.

Comment: Instrument the copy constructor as well as the `string` constructor and the destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
vector <Testi> a;
a.push_back(Testi("John"));
```

1. The `Testi("John")` creates a new, temporary Testi object.
2. `push_back` copies that object into the vector.
3. Then the temporary object is deleted.

So the unexpected constructor and destructor calls come from the creation and deletion of the temporary.  You can avoid the extra temporaries and copies by using `emplace_back` which will construct the object directly in the vector.

Comment: If the OP can call `emplace_back` then there is no copy going on.  The temporary is moved into the vector.  Me thinks C++ is not turned on/available.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Is that different than what I wrote?

Comment: Actually, `emplace_back` would construct the object directly in place. No temporaries at all. @nathan

Comment: Yes.  *push_back makes a copy of that object to put it in the vector.* is not true if the parameter is a temporary.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  OK, I fixed the wording on `push_back`.  I thought you were talking about what I wrote about `emplace_back`.

Comment: Well something strange occurs.
I replace all push_back's with emplace_back and it still makes same output.

Comment: Did you write `a.emplace_back("Jack")` or `a.emplace_back(Testi("Jack"))`?

Comment: @NathanOliver:  The OP has a user-declared destructor, which suppresses the implicit move constructor.  Therefore the temporary is copied, not moved.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy eh, yes, i used it in bad way. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Good call.  Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more clear add the copy constructor for the class for example the following way as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Testi {
public:

    string name;
    Testi(const string &a) : name(a) {
        cout << "Im alive: " << name << endl;
    }
    Testi( const Testi &t ) : name(t.name + "_copy") {
        cout << "Im alive: " << name << endl;
    }
    ~Testi() {
        cout << "Im no longer alive: " << name << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    {
        vector <Testi> a;

        a.push_back(Testi("John"));
        a.push_back(Testi("Jack"));
        a.push_back(Testi("Jake"));

        cout << "---------------------" << endl;

        for (const auto &item : a) cout << item.name << ' ';
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    {
        cout << "---------------------" << endl;
        vector <Testi> a;
        a.reserve(3);

        a.emplace_back("John");
        a.emplace_back("Jack");
        a.emplace_back("Jake");

        cout << "---------------------" << endl;

        for (const auto &item : a) cout << item.name << ' ';
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Im alive: John
Im alive: John_copy
Im no longer alive: John
Im alive: Jack
Im alive: John_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: John_copy
Im alive: Jack_copy
Im no longer alive: Jack
Im alive: Jake
Im alive: John_copy_copy_copy
Im alive: Jack_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: John_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: Jack_copy
Im alive: Jake_copy
Im no longer alive: Jake
---------------------
John_copy_copy_copy Jack_copy_copy Jake_copy

Im no longer alive: John_copy_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: Jack_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: Jake_copy
---------------------
Im alive: John
Im alive: Jack
Im alive: Jake
---------------------
John Jack Jake

Im no longer alive: John
Im no longer alive: Jack
Im no longer alive: Jake
```

So in this statement

```
a.push_back(Testi("John"));
```

there is created a temporary object as result of the expression `Testi("John")`.
Then this object is copied to the vector and the vector stores a copy of the temporary object. At the end of the statement the temporary object is deleted.

```
Im alive: John
Im alive: John_copy
Im no longer alive: John
```

When this statement is executed

```
a.push_back(Testi("Jack"));
```

the same operations are performed except that the vector needs to reallocate memory that to accommodate the new element.

```
Im alive: Jack
Im alive: John_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: John_copy
Im alive: Jack_copy
Im no longer alive: Jack
```

the first message corresponds to creating the temporary object that corresponds to the argument `Testi("Jack")`. Then the current element of the vector is copied to the new extent of memory due to the memory reallocation

```
Im alive: John_copy_copy
Im no longer alive: John_copy
```

then the new element is copied and the temporary object is deleted

```
Im alive: Jack_copy
Im no longer alive: Jack
```

and so on.

If you will reserve enough memory in the vector then there will no memory reallocation. Also if you will use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` there will not be created temporary objects. In this case the output will be

```
Im alive: John
Im alive: Jack
Im alive: Jake
```

and

```
Im no longer alive: John
Im no longer alive: Jack
Im no longer alive: Jake
```

Comment: To make it even clearer, add a move c'tor, a copy-assignment operator, and a move-assignment operator. ;-)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy There will be a too long output. It is clear enough what is behind the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a temporary object as a parameter to `push_back`. the temporary is being copied and after that its lifetime expires, thus it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If you would overload the copy and move constructors (and track instances for convenience) you will see what is going on [there](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3874ec0319b17a7f)

```
struct Testi {
    static int instanceCount;
    
    std::string name;
    int instanceIndex;
    
    Testi(Testi&& other) : name(other.name), instanceIndex(++instanceCount) {
        std::cout <<other.instanceIndex << " => " << instanceIndex << " move constructor " << name << std::endl;
    }
    
    Testi(const Testi& other) : name(other.name), instanceIndex(++instanceCount) {
        std::cout <<other.instanceIndex << " => " << instanceIndex << " copy constructor " << name << std::endl;
    }
    Testi(std::string a) : name(a), instanceIndex(++instanceCount) {
        std::cout << instanceIndex << " Im alive: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    ~Testi() {
        std::cout << instanceIndex << " Im no longer alive: " << name << std::endl;
    }
};

int Testi::instanceCount = 0;
```

> 1 Im alive: John
> 1 => 2 move constructor John
> 1 Im no longer alive: John
> 3 Im alive: Jack
> 3 => 4 move constructor Jack
> 2 => 5 copy constructor John
> 2 Im no longer alive: John
> 3 Im no longer alive: Jack
> 6 Im alive: Jake
> 6 => 7 move constructor Jake
> 5 => 8 copy constructor John
> 4 => 9 copy constructor Jack
> 5 Im no longer alive: John
> 4 Im no longer alive: Jack
> 6 Im no longer alive: Jake
> Jack
>
> 8 Im no longer alive: John
> 9 Im no longer alive: Jack
> 7 Im no longer alive: Jake

1 - temporary object that is being passed as an argument to `push_back()`
2 - object stored in the vector created by moving (or copying)
3 - another temporary object
4 - object that is stored in a vector
5 - copy of the object 2 because vector needs to reallocate
And so on. But this will give you general idea of implementation (and why one might want to `reserve()`). Standard does not restrict what exactly should be used. Here we should also talks about versions:

- Before C++11 contained type should be copy-constructible and copy-assignable
- Starting from C++11 restrictions are applied to a specific function; for `push_back()` contained type should be [CopyInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable) and [MoveInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveInsertable)

This should give you general expectations of implementation.